# How to serialize protobuf from json with auto ignoring unknown fields in c#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, protocol-buffers, proto3

For example, I have a proto like this:

```
message ProtoType
{
    string field1 = 1;
    strin field2 = 2;
}
```

And I have a json deserialized from a newer version of this proto:

```json
{
  "field1": "111",
  "field2": "222",
  "testField": "test"
}
```

I use this to serialize protobuf from json:

```cs
JsonParser.Default.Parse<ProtoType>(protojson);
```

However, if my json has some fields that don't exist in proto (like the `testField` below), it will throw an exception:

```
InvalidProtocolBufferException: Unknown field: testField
```

I wonder if there's a way to get a ProtoType instance which can automatically ignore unknown fields.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the class `JsonParser.Setting` and use the function `WithIgnoreUnknownFields`. So you will have something like this:

```cs
var settings = JsonParser.Settings.Default.WithIgnoreUnknownFields(true);
var t = new JsonParser(settings).Parse<Test.ProtoType>(protojson);
```

Furthermore, the documentation doesn't seem to be covering that. I recommend that you check the [JsonParser source code](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/JsonParser.cs) and search for the `Settings` class to get all the functions you can use.

## Edit

For completeness, there is a [copy of the C# documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Protobuf/latest/Google.Protobuf.JsonParser.Settings) managed by the Google cloud team and this one is up-to-date.